How might digitigrade races in a predominantly plantigrade society cope with the problems that come with structures not being designed for them?
In my fantasy/sci-fi/speculative writings, I have several digitigrade beings. The Salamandrion (whom I've talked about before) are one of them, but the Argonite and Drachenheul races, displayed in this drawing, also have this foot structure:

I apologize for my mediocre art skills, but this is the best I can do.
While looking over my designs, and also walking around on my tiptoes for a little while/studying my dog's paws to try and gauge what it might be like, I realized a bit of a problem. These creatures most likely have a strange center of balance compared to us humans, which, in my testing, causes some trouble on stairs, for example. Now you might say, "Well, they just never came up with stairs then and just used ramps or ladders, or just flew (in the case of the winged species)" and this makes sense for the architecture on Drachenwelt or Australis or one of the Drachenheul or Argonite-controlled planets, but they aren't the only creatures in the galaxy and they aren't restricted to those planets.
The vast majority of the sapient races are plantigrade; Humans and Ailurids, both of which have a plantigrade foot structure, are behind much of the design world in this universe, and thus create most of their buildings, vehicles, devices, etc. with human-like feet in mind.
There's no real pressure for this to change, at least not yet in the time period the story happens in (the equivalent of the late 1960's). Elevators exist if you're wondering, but you can't put an elevator just to go up a couple feet to someone's house that's elevated off the ground, and what about places without electricity but with a mixed-species population?
All this to say, what would a digitgrade being have to do to go about life in a world clearly not designed for his body shape?

Ostriches manage. They can walk/run and are perfectly capable of standing on the spot without issues. Depends on what they evolved to be able to cope with.

Most dogs can also go up & down stairs.  The "strange center of balance" for a digitigrade human (you) is because we default to plantigrade.  Presumably evolved-as-digitigrade 2-leggers would find that posture normal, due to different weight distribution and hip structure.

Why can't you put an elevator to go up a couple feet? Most often these are called accessibility lifts, but the function is the same.

An Important Point
When I saw @Escapeddentalpatient.'s comment and @Kilisi's answer I decided to convert my comment to an answer, because you've solved your own problem — you just don't realize it.
Let's start with You Can't Climb a Mountain With Ostrich Legs. You can't! The lean-forward push-up motion needed for climbing a reasonably steep incline can't be accomplished with a digitigrade Ostrich leg. But there's something you need to consider.

The Ostrich leg has two major joints. Let's call the upper one the "knee" and the lower one the "ankle." See how they're designed? Any effort to climb an incline of more than a handful of degrees would cause the bird to topple over backwards. The rotation motion of the "hip" allows it to move forward (which it can do with considerable speed), but it can't climb a set of stairs that aren't really, really shallow.
Now let's look at the mountain goat!

It has not two, but three major joints: the ankle, the digitigrade "knee" and a plantigrade knee.
BTW: I know that I'm completely referencing digitigrade joints incorrectly. I'm doing it on purpose. I want you to see the solution that you already have...
...because your drawings appear to show creatures with both a digitigrade joint and a plantigrade joint.
If that's true, you're golden. Your creatures might be a bit uncomfortable climbing stairs, etc., but as @Kilisi says, "mountain goats can go places most humans would balk at" and it's the combination of the two joint types that allows it. As @Kilisi pointed out, your creatures evolved that way, so they likely wouldn't even feel discomfort. They'd do it without thinking.
Now, if you really want those ostrich legs... you're hosed. Pure digitigrade legs would be forced to lean forward and hop stair-to-stair to climb them. And that's the best you could do.

Note that ostriches do have an actual knee, it's just hidden under the feathers because their thighs are very short.

@Vilarinof Check out this image of a cat's hind legs. Way at the bottom is the "ankle", then the degitigrade joint, then (like the mountain goat) a plantigrade joint, then the hip. They're not like ostriches. They're like mountain goats, which is why they don't have trouble climbing mountains. As for the OP's picture, it looks to me that both joints are represented, but that's really for the OP and not us to decide.

@JBH, I think what he means is that a cat/dog walks on their metacarpophalangeal joints.  A goat is an ungulate that walks on the tips of its distal phalanges where the MCPs form a sort of second ankle.   I don't know how big of a difference it makes in any practical way, but it is a difference.

To those involved in this discussion, yes, the cat/dog paw concept is closest to what I was imagining for these characters. The one on the right, the Drachenheul, is derived from a wolf-like creature and thus “dog paws” would be the best way to describe their feet. The Argonite on the left has the same basic leg structure internally, although outwardly the legs have scales and a more theropod-like appearance. (Argonites are a mammalian species, simply with some reptilian characteristics; think of how a platypus has a beak or a pangolin has scales.)

@JBH You and Vilarinof are actually describing digitigrade legs the same way, you've just got your anatomical analogues slightly off. What you're referring to as the "ankle" in that picture is the phalangeal joint, and the actual ankle what you called the "digitigrade joint". That's what "digitigrade" means: it's an animal that walks on its toes, thus "digit". The entire paw structure of a cat is made up of just its phalanges.

This differs from the legs of ungulates like goats, because their toes (like Vilarinof mentioned) are perpendicular to the ground, more like a ballet stance. The part of the foot that makes contact with the ground is the tip of their toes, not the bottom surface of their toes.

@Nosajimiki it's a difference, but my argument is the double opposing joint solves the problem. So far, the examples we have of mountain-climing digitigrade creatures are those with double opposing joints.

@Idran :-) I even mentioned in my post that I was completely ignoring the proper nomenclature. However, I've noticed over the years that whenever a querent posts a question about digitigrade creatures, what's in their head is the backwards-operating knee joint, not the toes/fingers/digits. Frankly, a comprehensive and canonical post about practical bipedal digitigrade legs would go a long way on this site - but I'm not qualified to create it.

@Vilarinof There are always more factors to consider, but I'm personally unconvinced that since evolution hasn't taken cats and mountain goats (etc) to a bipedal form, that it can't. The goal of this stack is to help the querent rationalize rules for an imaginary world - not to teach a science class. I believe I've done that in spades.

You have the versatility issue backwards.
Humans often switch to digitigrade when doing a wide variety of things including but not limited to going up and down stairs, climbing ladders, and operating the pedals on a car. This is because a flat footed step is only beneficial on flat ground where the rolling action can be used to reduce shock, or if you need to carry a heavy load. But, if you are dealing with any sort of obstacle or limited step space, this rolling action actually interrupts your gait making digitigrade better.  Likewise, if you are trying to do any sort of pushing off action, or precision manipulation, you will use your foot in a digitigrade fashion so that you can engage your lower leg muscles for more controlled movement. This is the whole reason most gas/break pedals are only big enough for the balls of your feet and do not come all the way down to the floor.

The only reason a digitigrade humanoid might struggle to function in a plantigrade world would be in a setting where long marches or heavy labor are a normal and expected part of life.  So, in a forced march, survival, or labor camp sort of setting, a Salamandrion may have a really hard time keeping up with Humans, but in a sci-fi starship sort of setting, where they just need to be able to function in the same space as the humans to do normal high-tech sorts of jobs, the lack of a plantigrade option will not hinder their ability to function in any meaningful way.
Who Really Needs Special Accommodations?
As established, humans are not obligate plantigrade creatures meaning we may prefer plantigrade locomotion in certain circumstances but have no trouble functioning in digitigrade.  So, if your spaceship is designed with humans in mind, then your obligate digitigrades should be fine because their feet are already optimized for the same complex actions that the functional plantigrades are optimized for.
However, what if your setting has actual obligate plantigrades?  While humans and Salamandrions may  use stairs, ladders, and foot pedals just fine, what if one of your other races can only operate in plantigrade, more like a bear?  In general, obligate plantigrades have shorter/wider feet than humans because they are designed to distribute weight, not lift up for extra power.  If this is the case, then ladders could pose a major issue because they can not insert their feet between rungs without their shins getting in the way of the rung above it.  Foot pedals may also be more difficult to control with shorter feet because you'd be unable to rest your heel on the ground and reach the lever with your toes; so, you'd have to hold your foot up in the air to operate standard human foot pedals.
These minor issues would not be hard to fix though.  Ladders would work just fine for obligate plantigrades if each rung has alternating protruding steps.  This way each step is guaranteed clearance above it as it climbs regardless of the steepness of the ladder.  As for foot pedals, they could just be made adjustable similar like how a steering wheel can be raised and lowered to accommodate drivers of different proportions.

Your tails and wings of course will need additional special accommodations, but that is a different problem all together.

Actually since many of the other sapient beings (for example, the aforementioned Ailurids) also have tails, it’s kinda standard that all seats have tail holes. Wings might be a problem, yes, but as you said that’s a completely different discussion.

@KeilahH That's good.  Just remember that human backs don't do well sitting a long time without lumbar support; so, if you want the same chairs usable across species you may want to consider highly adjustable chairs like ergonomic office chairs, but with even more options.  Like the lumbar support can fold up behind the chair specifically for tailed users, and maybe the sides of the upper back seat can fold back to make room for wings or forward for users with protruding spines.

It’s funny that you used a bear as your pure plantigrade example, because I do actually have a bearlike race, the Arcturans. Your ideas on how to accommodate them are helpful!

No problem here.
You're unbalanced trying something new. They were born like that and have a lifetimes practice getting around. Birds, kangaroos, jerboas etc,. have no issues getting around. Mountain goats can go places most humans would balk at.
Your pictures have tails to balance with. They should be fine.

They would be fine. With the one on the left, you actually over-corrected with the tail, its too big and would force the centre of balance backward.
Either make the creatures lean a bit forward, like a kangaroo or a raptor, or make the tail smaller.
You might also want to make their shoulders narrower, and chest smaller, to move the centre of balance into the pelvis.
And of course consider that your creatures are not going to be standing around all day, imagine them sitting, squatting, sleeping etc.
The tail and the wings pose an obvious problem when using a chair, a couch, or even a bed not designed for them. I think you should consider that your creatures might feel the most comfortable squatting, even for sleep.
The lait and the wings would be a bit awkward in cramped spaces as well, so corridors, rooms, elevators, and doorways would have to be designed to accomodate those.
On another note, how do your creatures use the bathroom? That tail is going to make using a standard toilet a challenge.
Your creatures seem to move around barefoot (which makes sense, since their feet are not compatible with any kind of shoes). Does that mean that they track mud everywhere, and ruin the carpet with their talons?
What about vehicles? do they drive anything? Because standard human cars, coaches, carts, rowboats, cannoes, bicycles etc etc are going to be really awkward for them. Scooters though would work great.
As for your question about stairs: I thing there should be no problem going up; the only difference would be that they would probably "bound" up several stairs at a time, not tiptoe up like a human. Going down however would be awkward, they would be prone to tip forward too much.
The solution here is to make the stairs big and deep, about 2-3 times bigger than what is made for humans, (and more durable, since your creatures are going to gauge the stairs with their talons all the time).
But really, your creatures are mostly just going to skip the stairs entirely in many cases. Their digitgrade feet and plantigrade knees mean they can just leap up and down a story with no issues. Hopefully without landing someone.

Ha, the toilet problem I already kinda figured out (it was the first thing I had to get out of the way when I realized I was going to make them tailed creatures) And yes, they do drive vehicles, however they’re mostly starships and such and thus would probably have different controls as opposed to cars and stuff in our world.

Also, the tail length I think is more the fault of me being inconsistent with how I draw his tail as opposed to an actual design flaw.
